# Procedure created with CREATE PROCEDURE Defaults with ALTER PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Script that creates a procedure that looks like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.InitMyTable') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[InitMyTable] 

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InitMyTable] AS

BEGIN
CREATE TABLE MyTable (

    ID int,
    Name varchar(16),
    Data text

);
END
```

And it creates a procedure that looks like this:

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InitMyTable]    Script Date: 5/19/2017 12:30:45 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InitMyTable] AS

BEGIN
CREATE TABLE myTable (

    ID int,
    Name varchar(16),
    Data text

);
END
```

My issue is that the created procedure does not create the table, but when I remove the line

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InitMyTable] AS
```

It obviously works fine.

How can I create a script that produces a procedure without that line?

Comment: Not sure what your asking, CREATE just creates, it does not execute the contents of the SP.  If in SSMS you choose to *modify* then ALTER gets added for you for convenience.  If you want to execute the sp, EXEC it ...

Comment: Why do you want to create a table with a stored procedure? Your procedure will fail the second time it runs. And stop using the text datatype. It has been deprecated for well over a decade in favor of varchar(max).

Comment: And if you want to execute DDL statements inside a procedure it will have to be with dynamic sql...yet another shining example that something is not designed well here.

Comment: @AlexK. This is when I call the SP after it is created

Comment: By "call" do you mean you right-click it and select "Modify"? This is exactly by design. If you want to open the script as a CREATE PROCEDURE, then don't choose MODIFY, choose SCRIPT > AS CREATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you scripted out the stored procedure somehow-- possibly in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) by right-clicking the proc in the Object Explorer window and clicking "Modify".  When you do this, SSMS generates a script for you that will alter the existing stored procedure.

The DDL statements below *create* the procedure, but they are not *part of* the procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.InitMyTable') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[InitMyTable] 

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InitMyTable] AS
```

The same thing applies to the code generated by SSMS.  SSMS has generated code that can alter an existing stored procedure, but the DDL below is not actually part of the proc itself:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InitMyTable]    Script Date: 5/19/2017 12:30:45 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InitMyTable] AS
```

The stored procedure code itself is still there:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(16),
    Data text
);
```

Note that if this stored procedure is run twice, it will fail, because the table MyTable will already exist.  To avoid this error, the procedure could first check to see if the table exists:

```
if not exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'MyTable')
begin
    create table MyTable...
end
```